# can't make juju charm-store server?

Tags: go

I am trying to run juju charm-server in my local machine.I followed these steps.(https://github.com/juju/charmstore) but it gives this error.When i enter make command it gives this one.

```
Makefile:49: *** Cannot build; /home/sajith/Projects/Backup/charm-store-server/charmstore is not on GOPATH.  Stop
```

In my bash file I have added

```
GOROOT=/home/sajith/install/go/go
GOPATH=/home/sajith/Projects/Backup/charm-store-server/charmstore
```

and then export GOROOT and GOPATH

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$GOROOT/bin
export GOROOT
export GOPATH
```

I want to know how to setup these Go variable for run juju charm-store server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `GOPATH` should be:

```
GOPATH=/home/sajith/Projects/Backup
```

Then a go get would put the project in

```
/home/sajith/Projects/Backup/src/github.com/juju/charmstore
```

A `GOPATH` defines a **[workspace](http://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces)** in which go will create `src`, `pkg` and `bin` folders.
`go get` will get sources in `$GOPATH/src`.

Comment: Thanks but my src files are under this folder.(charmstore)

Comment: i change path still not working.it says package launchpad.net/godeps: cannot download, $GOPATH not set

Comment: Do a go get, and check if you see a src folder under your GOPATH

Comment: yes it creates src file.Now i want to build the project.How i can do that.these command need to be run.make sysdeps,make server.is these file in src folder or my downloaded location.

Comment: @Sajith4U in `$GOPATH/src/github.com/uju/charmstore`

Comment: Thanks i am new to go language.But when i try to run make install command it filed.Then says go install  -v github.com/juju/charmstore/...
store.go:22:2: cannot find package "github.com/juju/loggo" in any of:
 /home/sajith/install/go/go/src/pkg/github.com/juju/loggo (from $GOROOT)
 /home/sajith/Projects/Backup/src/github.com/juju/loggo (from $GOPATH)

Comment: branch.go:15:2: cannot find package "gopkg.in/juju/charm.v2" in any of:
 /home/sajith/install/go/go/src/pkg/gopkg.in/juju/charm.v2 (from $GOROOT)
 /home/sajith/Projects/Backup/src/gopkg.in/juju/charm.v2 (from $GOPATH)
config.go:11:2: cannot find package "launchpad.net/goyaml" in any of:
 /home/sajith/install/go/go/src/pkg/launchpad.net/goyaml (from $GOROOT)
 /home/sajith/Projects/Backup/src/launchpad.net/goyaml (from $GOPATH)
lpad.go:12:2: cannot find package "launchpad.net/lpad" in any of:

Comment: Is that problem with GO or any other problem.

Comment: @Sajith4U What is your GOPATH set to? (just to be sure)

Comment: As you said GOPATH=/home/sajith/Projects/Backup

Comment: i created go path and excute this command.go get -u -v -t github.com/juju/charmstore/...

Comment: @Sajith4U branch.go is from https://github.com/juju/charmstore/blob/v4/_old/branch.go: and `_old` folder: pretty sure you are not supposed to compile that;

Comment: now that error is not comming now i got this one it is reagrding GO.go install  -v github.com/juju/charmstore/...
../utils/password.go:13:2: cannot find package "code.google.com/p/go.crypto/pbkdf2" in any of:
 /home/sajith/install/go/go/src/pkg/code.google.com/p/go.crypto/pbkdf2 (from $GOROOT)
 /home/sajith/Projects/Backup/src/code.google.com/p/go.crypto/pbkdf2 (from $GOPATH)
make: *** [install] Error 1